# GHC 7.10.x migration: why can't one write "pure = return" in the instance Applicative?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I was reading an article about [GHC 7.10.x Migration](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Migration/7.10). There are some suggestions for fixing errors.

> GHC says `No instance for (Applicative ...)`
>
> If GHC complains that
>
> Foo.hs:7:10:
>       No instance for (Applicative Foo) arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
>       In the instance declaration for ‘Monad Foo’ then an easy way to fix this error is by defining an Applicative (and possibly a Functor)
>   instance: instance Functor Foo where
>           fmap  = liftM
>           -- or alternatively:
>           --  fmap = m >>= pure . f
>
> ```
> instance Applicative Foo where
>     -- NB: DO NOT USE `pure = return`
>     pure  = {- move the definition of `return` from the `Monad` instance here -}
>
>     (<*>) = ap  {- defined in Control.Monad -}
>     -- or alternatively:
>     --  f1 <*> f2 = f1 >>= \v1 -> f2 >>= (pure . v1)
>
>     -- NB: DO NOT USE `(*>) = (>>)`
>     (*>) = {- move the definition of `>>` from the `Monad` instance here -}
>
> instance Monad Foo where
>     return = pure {- definition moved to `Applicative(pure)` -}
>
>     (>>) = (*>) {- definition moved to `Applicative((*>))` -}
>
>     {- ...retain other previous definitions... -}
> ```

There are the NBs: `` DO NOT USE `pure = return` `` and `` DO NOT USE `(*>) = (>>) ``. Why can't one use it?

P.S. I tried to use it and it has been compiled.

Comment: This would lead to recursive definitions: the `Monad` instance functions are defined in terms of the `Applicative` instance functions, so you can't also go the other way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @WillSewell hinted in the comment, from `base-4.8.0.0` now `return` in type class `Monad` has a default implementation:

```
class Applicative m => Monad m where
    return      :: a -> m a
    return      = pure
```

By defining `pure = return` and forget to implement `return` manually one may create an infinite loop of definition which will pass the compilation and can only be detected at runtime.

---

`>>` is a different story for now. It has a default implementation relays on `>>=` only:

```
(>>) :: forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b
m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k
```

and by `*> = >>` you won't create an infinite loop unless you use `*>` in the definition of `>>=`, but there are [some concern](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Proposal/MonadOfNoReturn) about the possible next major change in `base` (which may change the default implementation of `>>` to `>> = *>`) so `*> = >>` is discouraged for forward compatibility.